# YouTube Android Player API - how to open links in the API instead of YouTube app?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am using the YouTube Android Player API which can play the YouTube videos.

When I click to another video inside the player like a video inside the `MORE VIDEOS`, it always opens the video in the YouTube app.

How to open the video and stay in the API player?